# Is the term moai used in Japanese?

Tags: translation, colloquial-language, word-requests

It is a group of people who get together monthly, to contribute and receive emotional assistance, advice, and financial support on a rotating basis. The term is called moai in Okinawa, but it may be a local language term. I want to find the Japanese equivalent. Thank you.

Comment: What is this called in English?

Comment: My female friend meets with a group of friends, contributes money to the group, and it is given to one who is in need, and the following month, another member is selected. This occurs on a monthly basis, the way I understand it.

Comment: So it's like a private welfare system...? Is this friend of yours Japanese or why do you think that there would be a Japanese term for this when you can't even explain it properly in English...?

Comment: The term is called something like Moai/Mouai but I am unable to locate a proper Japanese term. Thank you.

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A8%A1%E5%90%88　「模合」だって～初めて聞きます

Comment: I knew those things done amongst men from Okinawa. And those mutual-aid customs are virtually seen only among them. We don't omit Okinawa dialects from Japanese language groups. Thus it's still もあい in standard Japanese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A moai is an informal group created by people who commit to offer emotional, social or even financial assistance to one another.   The concept originated when farmers would meet on a regular basis to discuss the best ways to plant crops and how to support one another should their crops fail. 
Today, members of these social cooperatives meet one another’s practical needs—problem-solving, planning, pooling resources and collaborating.  They also serve as extended family where social and emotional needs are met—managing a crisis, reducing stress, connecting emotionally and, at times, assuaging grief.  Essentially, a moai is a group of people who “have your back” and commit to all aspects of well-being.

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A8%A1%E5%90%88
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moai_(social_support_groups)