# Is a 模合 considered to be a type of クラブ ？

Tags: meaning, words

I posted a question a while back concerning the term moai and I am trying to explain it others. Would it be considered a type of club?

Comment: Your last sentence, "Is a 模合 a type of クラブ", is a reasonable question, but "Is there a difference between 模合 and クラブ" is a poor way of asking your real question... [You know about 模合 better than most native Japanese speakers](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44680/5010), and you know how it's different from ordinary clubs in general.

Comment: I will amend my question to reflect your comments, since I am not a native speaker of Japanese.

Comment: Apparently, my definition is different from the overall understanding of the word club in Japanese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knew nothing about [模合](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A8%A1%E5%90%88) because I'm not from Okinawa, but judging from the description on Wikipedia and some other articles on the net, I think it's **not** safe to start your explanation like "模合とはクラブの一種で…". Instead, you can say "模合とは会の一種で…" or "模合とは互助会のようなもので…".

The main two purposes of 模合 seem to be "to help one another financially" and "to hold drinking parties regularly". The former is the original purpose, and the latter is often the "true" purpose today :) However, neither of the two is associated with what people usually imagine with the word クラブ. While there are many different types of クラブ (including sport clubs and even nightclubs), they are generally for entertaining or socializing people via some shared interest. A typical クラブ is not for mere casual drinking or for helping people financially. 会 is a very broad and vague term which can refer to any type of organization/group/gathering, so I think this is suitable to start your explanation.

Comment: Actually, the financial aspect is still of primary importance according to my friend, who is a member of 4 moai groups.

Comment: @JACK If so, calling it a type of クラブ is even less suitable IMHO.

Comment: i certainly agree, i like the term meeting much better!